# "rows" attribute of PageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce

Can somebody please explain to me what is the usage of `rows` attribute of `pageBlockTable` in visualforce pages ?

I've searched for the same but still not found anything except -
`The number of rows in this page block table.`

If I am not wrong, then number of rows of a pageBlockTable is decided by the size of list it has as a `value`. Then what is the use of `rows` attribute ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Rows" limit the no of rows to display on the Page .

Lets say your list has size of 10 rows but you still want to limit to 5 you can specify rows="5".

Please note same can also be done by putting a limit clause in the query if list is populated via query .

Comment: I also thought the same usage first, but when I tried to implement it, it was not showing any result. My list was having 4 elements, I specified rows="2". Still table had all the rows which were present in the list. What did I missed ?

Comment: As per the @Mohith Shrivastava its working fine.
**<apex:pageblockTable value="{!RegDisplayRecord}"  var="Reg" rows="2"> **